# How to create a json programatically with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to read from database a set of values and i would like to construct it as JSON with Javascript. Is there a way i can do it.
I do not want to simply have it appended as String in JAvascript.

Can anybody please help me out ?

Comment: why not use JSON.stringify?

Comment: Use json_encode() if your backend is in PHP.

Comment: @IamDesai : Thanks for your advise.. i have used json_encode() and it works like a charm.. Unfortunately for this usecase my backend is not PHP and i will not be able to use it..

Comment: @user3176143 Lookup for an equivalent for the language that you are using.

Comment: I want to do it with Javascript.. I constructed a String in JSON format and then used JSON.stringify.. And it worked.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just build a javascript object

```
var myJsonObj = {name:"Some Value"};
```

If you need it in string format you can do the following:

```
JSON.stringify(myJsonObj);
```

Comment: That would just be a JavaScript object, not actual JSON.

Comment: http://www.json.org/js.html JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript

Comment: They *look* the same (because JSON borrowed from JS), but they *aren't* the same (particularly here in the context of JS code). Your edit that added `JSON.stringify` is an important bit.

Comment: I think stringify is not needed explicitly. Just passing the key value pairs object does the job. I've been using it. Stringify only represents the object as a readable string.

Comment: JSON is java script object notation, so a javascript object defines json. The string form is just a format that can be deserialized in to a json object. It's needed if you have to send it over http etc

Comment: A JS object can define what JSON data looks like, but it's not JSON itself. JSON is *based on* a subset of JS object literal notation ([their site says as much](http://json.org/)), but that doesn't mean it IS. Deserializing JSON will put it into a format native to the language. In JS, that's a JS object (that simply looks like JSON because of JSON's history, formatting choices, and definition). In Java, for example, it'd be some custom object. I bring this up because OP seems like a beginner in this area, and beginners often think JS objects are literally JSON, when that is simply not true.

Answer (score 1):

what's your backend language?
for most of the languages will provide a function called jsonEncode()
you may try this.

take php for example

```
<?php
$yourphparray = array(
    "key1"=> "value1",
    "key2"=> "value2",
    "key3"=> "value3"
);
echo json_encode($yourphparray); 
?>
```

you may get the json like this

```
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }
```

if you just return as a string, you may have to use the json2.js by Douglas Crockford; the json2.js provid a function

```
jsondecode(yourstring);
```

to make a string to a js object!

Comment: Thanks for helping out.. Is it possible to read from JSON and convert it to another JSON format ? in javascript..

Answer (score 0):

With this method

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(any_object_or_array);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

*PS: Read from database and store it to json in js... I assume you're with nodeJs*

Comment: Is it possible to read from JSON and convert it to another JSON format ? in javascript..

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I created a Javascript string which would be constructed in the form of JSON.
The after iterating through the source json and creating string in target json format i used JSON.stringify to convert it to JSON. Worked well.

Thanks for all replies.